# creating composite field in mysql

Tags: mysql, composite

I need to make column 'full_name' as composite column of columns 'first_name' and 'last_name' in MySQL. I can do the same in MS SQL using following syntax :

```
create table customer
(
    first_name varchar(100)
  , last_name  varchar(100)
  , full_name AS first_name + last_name
)
```

How can I do the same in MySQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: If I need to retrieve data from database on the basis of full_name, then I can do the same querying single column instead of concatenating columns each time. hence, I want to store computed value in the table at the time of data insertion.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 5.7.5+ supports computed/generated columns ([here](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/) is a introduction to the subject).  So you can do this as:

```
create table customer (
    first_name varchar(100),
    last_name  varchar(100),
    full_name varchar(200) AS (concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name))
);
```

Notes:  First, I assume you want a space between the names.  Second, string concatenation does not use `+` in MySQL.

In earlier versions of MySQL, you would need to use a view for this.

Comment: Simply awsome...!! _/\_

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update record once it will get inserted into the table:

```
UPDATE customer SET fullname=CONCAT(first_name,last_name)
```